# ActiveRecord group not returning hash with arrays of objects for values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I know this has been asked and answered a lot. I have two tables Foo and Bar.

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :bar
  ...
```

Foo has attributes of `id` and `name` and `bar_id`

and

```
class Bar < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :foos
  ...
```

Bar has the attributes, `id` and `name`.

When I simply try `Foo.group(:bar_id)` I get `#<Foo::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x3fdeac1cc274>`

With `Foo.group(:bar_id).count` I get `{5=>2, 1=>2}` the keys being the `bar_id` and the values the count of how many have that id.

What I'm trying to do is, group `Foo` on `Bar#name` with an array of `Foo`s as the values.

```
{
 'name1' => [#<Foo:0x00007fbd5894f698 id:1, name: 'thing'...}, ...],
 'name2' => [#<Foo:0x00017fbd5894f698 id:5, name: 'thing'...}, ...],
 ...
}
```

With `Foo.joins(:bar).group('bars.name').count` I am able to return `{"name1"=>2, "name2"=>2}` But not an array of the Foo models. I know it's because of the count. But without the count it simply returns `#<Foo::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x3fdeac1cc274>`

I see a lot of suggestions using [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by). I don't want to use an enumerable as I'm using ActiveRecord and as the records increase, it will drastically slow down the look up.

Comment: `ActiveRecord_Relation` is a set of records. You need to invoke `to_a` on it, or iterate over it.

Comment: @meagar I get this error when iterating or adding `to_a` : `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "foos.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "foos".* FROM "foos" INNER JOIN "bars" ON "...
               ^
: SELECT "foos".* FROM "foos" INNER JOIN "families" ON "bars"."id" = "fooss"."bar_id" GROUP BY bars.name
from /2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:603:in `async_exec'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed that you're using PostgreSQL. Why not then use the [json aggregation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) functions. It a bit differs from your desired result, but still contains the same information:

```
Bar
  .joins(:foos)
  .group("bars.name")
  .pluck("bars.name", "json_agg(json_build_object('id', foos.id, 'name', foos.name))")
  .to_h
```

The result is going to be:

```
{
 'name1' => [{id:1, name: 'thing'}, ...],
 'name2' => [{id:5, name: 'thing'}, ...],
 ...
}
```

Comment: I've only used `json_agg` once and am unfamiliar with `json_build_object`. guess I've got some reading to do. It's close though. That gives me something to work with. However, that throws all kinds of warnings about raw SQL and will be disallowed in Rails 6

Comment: Since this question, I've learned about using Arel.sql to get the raw sql warning to go away :D